# mscorsn.dll doesn't load when using ILMerge

Tags: .net, ilmerge, snk

I'm using the following command on cmd with Administrator priviliges:

```
ILMerge.exe  /wildcards /log:ILMerge.log /allowdup 
             /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" 
             /lib:"C:\SDK2016\SDK2016\Bin" 
             /lib:"packages\Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions.7.1.0.1\lib\net45" 
             /lib:"packages\log4net.2.0.5\lib\net45-full" 
             /keyfile:"Tools\Snk\XXX.snk" 
             /out:"c:\XXXALLMERGED.dll" 
             "c:\proj\alldlls\*.dll"
```

And I'm getting the following error at the end of the log file:

```
An exception occurred during merging:
Unable to load DLL 'mscorsn.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.MscorsnStrongNameSignatureGeneration(String wszFilePath, String wszKeyContainer, Byte[] pbKeyBlob, Int32 cbKeyBlob, IntPtr ppbSignatureBlob, IntPtr pcbSignatureBlob)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Since my targetframework is v4 and my folder is "v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319", I checked if mscorsn.dll exists there; and it exists.

So, what can be the problem? Can you please help?

Comment: Isolate the problem DLL by omitting it from the command, crystal ball says that it targets 2.0.50727.  Use ildasm.exe to verify.  Your /targetplatform argument [is dangerously wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/17034), you must fix that.

Comment: well @HansPassant ; I tried the same command without /targetplatform argument: and I'm getting the same error :)

How can I isolate the problem dll?

Comment: You isolate it by trying to run ILMerge multiple times.  Each time adding one more DLL.  When it fails you found the troublemaker.

Comment: @HansPassant well I have the log file though. Why try every single assembly? It can even be .Net framework's or Microsoft CRM SDK's. Too much assemblies are taking place ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same issue.
This answer [Unable to load DLL mscorsn.dll with ILMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925123/unable-to-load-dll-mscorsn-dll-with-ilmerge) helped to me.

(shortly: ilmerge requires .NET3.5 to be installed)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it.

Originally I generated a .PFX file to sign my assembly in Visual Studio (using the Signing tab in the project properties window). I then extracted the public key from the .PFX file into a .SNK file (using sn.exe).

When I tried to use ILMerge.exe and use the generated .SNK file I would get the `"Unable to load DLL 'mscorsn.dll'"` error.

I fixed it by deleting the .PFX and generated .SNK files. 
I then generated a new .SNK file as follows (in VS):

- Project Properties > Signing
- Choose a strong name key file: `<New>`
- Specify the file name for the .SNK file.
- Uncheck `Protect my key file with a password' < This seemed to do the trick.

This generated a new .SNK file and when I used that file with ILMerge the error disappeared.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Add  `/delaysign`  switch after the  `/keyfile`  . This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair out for 2 days straight trying to solve this on my machine and finally found the answer. Nothing worked from any of the suggestions pasted here. I finally searched the IlMerge github and found a post regarding the possible connection to MachineKeys folder not having proper permissions.

If anyone of You has the same issue and nothing works, please go to this directory:
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

And set the permissions to Read AND Write for MachineKeys folder:

[Permissions on MachineKeys folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bP2v.png)

This link helped me in setting the properly:

https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2020/01/12/solving-access-denied-in-crypto-machine-keys.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Removing the /keyfile argument worked. Well signing is another issue I guess. Don't know how to solve this but at least it worked this way.